# SVN updates summary

Tags: svn, commit, summary

I have checked out source code from a SVN server, which is not in my control. I would like to know whenever there are new updates available and classify those as modification, new additions etc. Googling led me to believe "svn status --show-updates" was the command I was looking for. However when I run it on the repository root, it does not gives me the A/M flags but just * in status column. Any ideas on how to get this? TIA.

Comment: Small world: <http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=511507>. I guess this question is considered to be "close enough" to count as programming related, here. :)

Comment: unwind , someone on HN suggested me to post here both the Qs are by me.

Answer (score 9):

A nice tool for the job is [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor).

Comment: Stefan, unfortunately I need this on linux.

Comment: I'm sorry, but CommitMonitor only runs on Windows. And I don't know if there's a similar tool for Linux - maybe someone else knows...

Answer (score 2):

[`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) shows you whether your working copy has any changes compared to the repository copy that you checked out.  the --show-updates flag shows whether updates are available on the server, and the * means that there are.

Edit: Ok, if you can go gui, i use subversive in eclipse, but in order to stay commandline, how about this.  What you want sounds similar to a dryrun of a merge... you want to see what all the A,D,M will happen when you update to the HEAD.  So try this:

```
svn merge --dry-run -r BASE:HEAD
```

Comment: John, exactly what I want to know, ie, if there are new or modified files on the repository.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out what you need.  a merge dryrun

Answer (score 1):

```
svn status --show-updates
```

will put * in front of every file that changed in repository since last update.

You can see detailed changes between your working copy base (last update) and current repository head using:

```
svn log --revision BASE:HEAD
```

Adding option --verbose will list all changed files prepended with M, A etc.
Adding option --quiet will hide commit messages.

**Update:**

```
svn diff --summarize --revision BASE:HEAD
```

will list all changed files prepended with M, A etc in all revisions in range collapsed in one list. I guess that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Try [eSvn](http://zoneit.free.fr/esvn/). It has a feature to show status of files/directories in real time.